# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException - three exceptions

Tags: java

Here is my code and I can't figure out why I'm getting the above error.  It says it is in line 17 which is the one that starts off as int num

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // The driver class should instantiate a Verify object with a range of 10 to 100.
        Verify verify = new Verify(10, 100);
        //It should then do the following:
        //Prompt the user to input a number within the specified range.
        System.out.print("Input a number between 10-100 inclusive: ");
        // Use a Scanner to read the user input as an int.
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine()); 
        try {
            //Call the validate method to validate that the number is within the range.
            verify.validate(num);
            //print the value if it is within the range. 
            System.out.println("Number entered: " + num);
        } catch (NumberNegativeException ex) {
            //Print an appropriate error message if the value is not within the range,
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        } catch (NumberLowException ex) {
            //Print an appropriate error message if the value is not within the range,
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        } catch (NumberHighException ex) {
            //Print an appropriate error message if the value is not within the range,
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex ) {
            System.out.println("You entered bad data." ); 
        }           
    }    
}
```

Comment: Well...what value are you entering?

Comment: @peter It might be, if the user is entering a bunch of white space before their number.

Answer (score 0):

call `nextInt();` on the scanner (`input`) instead of trying to parse the line.
Alternatively move the line `int num ...` inside the try block

Comment: Note that this doesn't consumes the "next line" character of the input. So, he may have problems in future inputs.

Comment: @Christian Well, not if he knows to watch out for the issue. Definitely worth bringing up though.